# Formula field from Multi picklist not updating

Tags: formula-field

I have two custom objects "Customer Use Case" and "Use Case" where "Use Case' is a Lookup on the "Customer Use Case" - I have created a formula field (ROI__c)on the **Customer Use Case** object which looks at the related **Use Case** -
The (ROI_Use_c) field on the **Use Case** field is multi-select.

The formula field is populated properly if the value in **Use Case** is the first one, but if it is any other, or multiple selections, it just returns the first value. If I change the value in the (ROI_Use_c) field on the **Use Case** and go back to the **Customer Use Case** the new value is not displayed?

Here is the Formula:

IF(INCLUDES( Use_Case__r.ROI__c , "Board of Directors"), "Board of Directors" + BR() , NULL) +
IF(INCLUDES( Use_Case__r.ROI__c , "C-Level "), "C-Level " + BR() , NULL) +
IF(INCLUDES( Use_Case__r.ROI__c , "Compliance "), "Compliance " + BR() , NULL) +
IF(INCLUDES( Use_Case__r.ROI__c , "Human Resources "), "Human Resources " + BR() , NULL) +
IF(INCLUDES( Use_Case__r.ROI__c , "Incident Management "), "Incident Management " + BR() , NULL) +
IF(INCLUDES( Use_Case__r.ROI__c , "Security "), "Security ", NULL)

Comment: try to remove all `+ BR()` - could be that `ROI__c` value isn't displayed properly because of these line breaks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... Turns out it was something much easier... and I only just caught it this morning with a fresh set of eyes... There was a space after each entry (but inside the quote marks) so when the formula ran and saw the value in the source field which did not have a space at the end, it did not match!  Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `NULL` instances and replace with empty string (`""`) - I think this will work, because when you add a string to `NULL` it generally returns `NULL`

Example:

```
IF(INCLUDES( Use_Case__r.ROI__c , "Board of Directors"), "Board of Directors" + BR() , "") + 
IF(INCLUDES( Use_Case__r.ROI__c , "C-Level "), "C-Level " + BR() , "") + 
IF(INCLUDES( ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did not work.  The results were the same as described in my initial post.  In the case where the Source field has let's say (3) values from the multi-picklist... only the first one is populating in the target field.